# DOM not updated when taken value from localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an  button as:

```
<ion-radio ng-repeat="business in multipleBusiness track by business.id" ng-model="choice.value" ng-value="business">{{business.name}}</ion-radio>
```

and In controller I am doing...

```
$scope.choice.value = localStorageService.get('defaultBusiness') || $scope.multipleBusiness[0];
```

Now the radio buttons are shown with a checkmark when the value passed to `$scope.choce.value` is `$scope.multipleBusiness[0]` but when the value from localStorage is used i.e. `localStorageService.get('defaultBusiness')` , the chekmark is not shown

Even though on consoling both the values are same structure i.e objects with id and name keys.

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorageService.get('defaultBusiness')` will return string. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to have it as an json object.

Comment: but typeof is giving the output from localStorage as object.

Comment: @DeanAmbrose Check https://plnkr.co/edit/b0hLbSmhxux2n6QXfuuk?p=preview. Refresh and see the console after selecting a value and see it for yourself.

Comment: @DeanAmbrose Did my suggestion worked in your case or not ? please confirm.

Comment: no...because you are stringifying the data before saving and then converting it back to json after getting from local storage. I have directly saved it to local storage as object hence I don't think I need to JSON,parse() as the data I am receiving is already in json form.

Comment: You don't need to stringify with this library (angular-local-storage) , because the set function utilizes angular's toJson() method under the hood. Similarly, the get method JSON.parse()s the item to return. No need for that either.

Comment: @DeanAmbrose I stringified because localstorage doesn't support `objects`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage . Share a plunkr so that I can see what exactly you have implemented